# Reproducing original Mario levels in Mario Maker?

Tags: super-mario-maker

In Super Mario Maker, with all the extra changes and removed elements, is it possible to create a level that is *exactly* like an original level in Super Mario Bros 1, 3, Super Mario World or Super Mario Bros Wii? I can accept not having the exact same backgrounds, as that would not affect game play.

Comment: You could probably recreate *most* levels, though for at least SMW there are some blocks/sprites that AFAIK aren't in Mario Maker (yet?). Like those triangles that let you run up walls. Some things that don't exist (like the expanding/contracting lines of blocks) you MIGHT be able to create approximations of with a little cunning (moving blocks on a track).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that for some worlds, *yes* it's possible.

Take world 1-4 from the first Super Mario Bros game.  Here is [a video](https://youtu.be/WFD-VAJDriY) of a near exact replica (with a few differences in textures and the floating bridge above Bowser at the end is longer than the originals) with the level ID in the description.  For comparison, here is [a video of the original game](https://youtu.be/GfroW2zfMH0).

There is also a [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/3y34xi/super_mario_bros_11_12/) for worlds 1-1 and 1-2.  They provide the level ID's, but whether or not they are exact I'm not sure since I can't play them.  It's mentioned that they are as close as possible to the originals with the exception of the limitations imposed in Super Mario Maker.

Comment: I created a near-block perfect version of SMB1 1-1 the first day the game came out.  The only missing things are: 1. the blocks containing a mushroom or fire flower because support for that didn't arrive for several months. 2. Mario Maker has a wider screen so enemies start moving earlier. 3. You can scroll the screen in either direction.

Comment: Having said that, you can't exactly duplicate a lot of levels because a lot of features are missing. Even SMB1 1-2 can't be exactly duplicated because of the elevators.

Answer (score 0):

There's one important thing in Mario Maker that you have to pay attention to if recreating a level from Mario 1, 3, or World. The physics engine used in Mario Maker is the same one used in New Super Mario Bros, which is different from those used in the original 1, 3, and world. And it uses the same physics engine no matter which types of game theme you choose.

This means that it could be possible to recreate a level that is 100% identical to a Super Mario World level in terms of the layout of each individual block, enemy, etc; but the level would play differently; and could even be impossible to beat in Super Mario Maker.

For example, in original Super Mario World, when you spin jump on an enemy and it dies, you don't bounce off of it at all; you go straight down. But in Super Mario Maker, spin jumping on an enemy to kill it causes you to bounce off it like you do with a normal jump. The basic mechanics of the angles and speeds of jumps differ as well.

That being said, the other answers are correct; you can recreate some levels, but not others; due to various types of enemies and blocks not existing in Mario Maker.

Source: http://nintendoeverything.com/why-super-mario-maker-uses-new-super-mario-bros-u-physics-for-all-game-styles/.

Answer (score -1):

First, do you mean the ENTIRE game? If so, I don't think so. Some levels have multiple exit pipes that lead to areas with different sprites and the sub-area would take up the entire length of the level anyways. So for the whole game, no. (But I would love to see an attempt). If you only mean one level, it depends on which level you select. For example, in Super Mario World, there are blocks that expand and compact up (like the ones in YI 3). Those (as far as I know) are not available in SMM. So, long story short, it depends on which level you pick to duplicate.

Comment: I was only asking about levels, I know we can't do the entire game.

Comment: Yeah, for levels, like I said, certain levels would work.

Comment: So is there an example of one, instead of examples of some that are not?

Comment: As you see ALL OVER SMM, you can recreate most of the original SMB. As for SMB3 and SMW. I don't know.  I haven't played the entire game, so I can't say. as for NSMBU, most levels have sprites (like the flying squrrel) that isn't in SMM. So, to recap: SMB - Probably. SMB3 & SMW - idk. NSMBU - Most likely not.